# Is it possible to know if a small avocado plant is going to be a fruitful tree?

Tags: growth, avocado

I started growing an avocado pit, which grew very nicely until now.

I was wondering if there's any way to know if it can become a fruitful tree - if so I'd like to plant it in my garden, but if it doesn't - I prefer not to.

The avocado was bought in a supermarket and I'm pretty sure it was a reed (if that matters), but not 100% sure.

[image]

Comment: That guy is ready for transplanting! Most of the avocados I see in supermarkets are Hass avocados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most avocado plants are hybrids and seeds will not necessarily come true from seed.  Fruit could be better, worse or the same.

Also, avocados are large trees.  Your chances of getting a crop from a plant in a pot grown inside are not very good. If you [search for avocado](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=avocado) on this forum you will see many very sad looking plants. They do not do well inside in pots over the long term.  Light levels are too low and there is insufficient space for the roots.

If you can plant it outside and you are in a tropical climate and can wait [five to seven years](http://ucavo.ucr.edu/general/answers.html#anchor733630) then it should start fruiting.

Comment: Sounds like a mission too me!

Comment: OP is from Israel and Reed avocado comes from California, so the climate is probably ok. But starting from seed, will definitely not guarantee edible fruit, use a graft if you want to be sure the fruit will be edible.

Comment: @kevinsky Thanks! I was planning to plant it in the garden in the ground, and not in a pot - so it's already a better start. So as I understand, anyways the chances aren't good for it to give edible fruit

Comment: @b.nota Thanks for your comment! I'm indeed from Israel, and I'm also pretty sure that we're raising avocado trees in the country. What do you mean by graft? I'm not familiar with the word and Google Translate gives me multiple different options. Buying seeds ready for planting? or the building of a tree on top of another one that has a big root?

Comment: Graft is indeed a clone on top of a root/stem of another plant. Like Kevinsky says in his answer, from seeds you don't know what kind of fruit the (genetically) new plant will produce. That's why cloning is done (also for e.g., apple trees). Then you know for sure what kind of fruits the plant will have (same as original tree).